# Appening values in a text field dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am generating the fields and the hidden fields dynamically.

Can anyone point me to right direction as how can i create one hidden fields with all values as comma seperated:

currently i am doing like this

```
if (iCnt <= 9999) {
        iCnt = iCnt + 1;
        $(newitems).append('<input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="'+iCnt+'"/>');
        $('.buttonsPlaceHolder').after(newitems);
    }
```

above creates 10 hidden fields with same name and id, if i generated 10 new textboxes

Comment: your problem is duplicate id?

Comment: Can i ask you why would you need that?

Comment: What does iCnt represent ?

Comment: iCnt is  loop which starts from 999

Comment: i know its a duplicate ID, what i am saying something i am missing here to bring all counters in one field using a comma separator,

Answer (score 1):

If you want one hidden field, create a string with all your values, comma separated, then insert it as value of the field :

```
var values = [], value = ""; // to declare before the beginning of the loop
if (iCnt <= 9999) {
    iCnt = iCnt + 1;
    values.push(iCnt);
}
value = values.join(",");
$(newitems).append('<input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="'+value+'"/>');
$('.buttonsPlaceHolder').after(newitems);
```

Comment: Maybe the append could be done this way:

    `$(newItems).append($('<input>')
        .attr('type', 'hidden')
        .attr('name', 'insertRecords')
        .attr('value', value)); `

Comment: @xartok: `<span><input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="1000"><input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="1000,1001"><input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="1000,1001,1002"><input type="hidden" name="insertRecords" id="insertRecords" value="1000,1001,1002,1003"></span>`

Comment: @john can you give the loop where the code you provided is executed ?
@Bustikiller or even `$(newItems).append($('<input>', {name: "insertRecords", value: value, type: "hidden", id: "insertedRecords"})`

Comment: @xatok: which loop exactly, it is all in the `if` condition

Comment: @John You say that iCnt is loop here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157368/appening-values-in-a-text-field-dynamically/32157559?noredirect=1#comment52202972_32157368) So how is it executed to loop 10 times for 10 textboxes for instance ?

Comment: i declared like this `var cnt = 999;if (iCnt <= 9999) {
    iCnt = iCnt + 1;
 -- do the job here --
}`

Comment: this code execute just once, and cnt (iCnt?) will never have a value over 1000... Maybe it's in a function that listen an event ?